# Spring Cloud Gateway - Compress all the responses

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using the Spring Cloud Gateway, version 2.2.7.RELEASE, as a gateway for a microservice application. We developed every microservice using Spring Boot. The responses coming from microservices are not compressed.

I am searching how to perform compression of responses directly in the gateway, maybe as a `GlobalFilter`. However, I am not finding any reference on the Internet.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than I thought.
It is sufficient to enable the property `server.compression.enabled` in the *application.yml* file. If you want to have a list of all the available options, look at the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties).

WARNING: The proxied microservices don't have to compress the response, too.